# ggplot: Why does scale_x_date need an additional element in date_labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a long dataframe, where I include the format for labels on the x-axis. For some reasons - which are hard to see in the small example - I would like to add the year on the first break and on the beginning of every year.

Using the (long) column for `date_labels` in `scale_x_date` is not working,
using the (original) column does not show what I'm expecting.

While writing this, I found a "solution", but I do not understand, why another element ("something") is needed.

Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)

t <- tibble(
  day   = as.Date(
          c("2019-11-01", "2019-12-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01")),
  a     = c(5           , 7           , 5           , 4           ) ,
  b     = c(6           , 6           , 4           , 6           ) ,
  label = c("%m\n%Y"    , "%m"        , "%m\n%Y"    , "%m"        )
) 

df <- t %>% 
  pivot_longer(c("a","b"), names_to="cat", values_to="value")
```

my first attempt:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = df, aes(x = day, y = value, fill = cat), stat = "identity", 
           position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month", date_labels = df$label)
# error "Breaks and labels are different lengths" fair enough
```

second attempt:

```
scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month", date_labels = t$label)
# not what I expected: %m %m\n%Y %m %m\n%Y
```

this works:

```
scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month", 
  date_labels = c("something", df$label[c(TRUE, FALSE)]))
```

but why do I have to insert "something"?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You have a column for date formats, but normally on a plot with a  continuous x axis there is not a one-to-one correspondence between x-axis breaks and the observations in your data frame (your example is no exception). It's therefore not clear how you expect row-wise formatting labels to work.

Comment: I agree, observations and breaks are independent. I could define the representations of the labels in a separate vector. However, the behavior is identical.

Comment: Most likely `scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month", date_labels = t$label)` is generating a lower left hand limit that which is in the vector but not plotted.